# I am trying to split an ascii text file into multiple data (frames/tables) when the number of columns changes in the input stream

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several hundred files, each of which contain blocks of data, the first block may have seven columns, the second two, the third five, etc.  The data in each block differs and contains new column headers.  I would like to split each block into a separate data frame.

Comment: How are you currently reading the data from the file? Is there any sort of delimiter/separator between the 'blocks'?

Comment: Welcome to SO, JAC! I suspect that this question has been asked-and-answered several times, but it's difficult to know which of the other answers to provide as a reference for you. Your question is lacking details that would help us in that fashion, in that it makes no effort at being *reproducible* so that we can help. In that end, up front: code attempted, sample data (e.g., first few lines of 2-4 files), and expected output. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thanks!

Comment: Data is separated by  blank line between blocks

Comment: df.data <- fread(infile, fill=TRUE).    Data Blocks are separated by a blank line.  Read works fine as long as the number of columns stays below the initial 12.  Last block has 13